# How to define condition for Radiobutton in a efficient way?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

i`m trying to find a efficient way to define conditions for radio-buttons.

[image]

After selecting a Radio-Button i should disable or fill the text-boxes. Following an example:

```
 private void Transportauftrag_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = true;
        groupBox8.Visible = false;
        StartGerät.Text = "";
        StartBlockFach.Text = "";
        StartTiefe.Text = "";
        ZielGerät.Text = "";
        ZielBlockFach.Text = "";
        ZielTiefe.Text = "";
        FehlerFehler.Text = "****";
        FehlerBereich.Text = "****";
        FehlerInfo.Text = "****";
        Transportbefehl.Text = "";
        Breite.Text = "";
        Tiefe.Text = "";
        Höhe.Text = "";
        Typ.Text = "";
        Folgeauftrag.Text = "";
        Behälternummer.Text = "";
        Reserve.Text = "";
        StartGerät.Enabled = true;
        StartBlockFach.Enabled = true;
        StartTiefe.Enabled = true;
        ZielGerät.Enabled = true;
        ZielBlockFach.Enabled = true;
        ZielTiefe.Enabled = true;
        FehlerFehler.Enabled = false;
        FehlerBereich.Enabled  = false;
        FehlerInfo.Enabled = false;
        Transportbefehl.Enabled = true;
        Breite.Enabled = true;
        Tiefe.Enabled = true;
        Höhe.Enabled = true;
        Typ.Enabled = true;
        Folgeauftrag.Enabled = true;
        Behälternummer.Enabled = true;
        Reserve.Enabled = true;
    }
```

So now i should do this 7 times.
And for this i need over 400 Line of Codes in my WindowsFormsApp-File.

Are they any better way / solution to do this?

Comment: `FehlerBereich.Enabled  = condition`.

Comment: Create a new method for initializing the text.  Then call the method from each of your 7 change events.

Comment: Add custom attributes to your filled buttons and emptied buttons. Like this `[Fill] class FehlerFehler` and `[Empty] class Transportbefehl`. And then iterate them using reflection looking for your custom attributes.

Answer (score 1):

ok here are some suggestions. Basically if faced with such a problem then it indicates that you need an organizational structure. Otherwise one gets lost. As it appears from the picture of your GUI you already have `GroupBox`es that organize this. All the labels and Textboxes inside that groupbox are in `groupBox1.Controls`. You can get them out in 1 blow even by type:

```
 List<TextBox> allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1 = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

Now you can iterate over it and write the same value for each Textbox:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1)
{
    tb.Text = "";
}
```

But you better make a method from it:

```
private void FillAllTextBoxes(GroupBox groupBox, string text)
{
    List<TextBox> allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1 = groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();

    foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1)
    {
        tb.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call it and pass the necessary input:

```
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxStart, "");
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxZiel, "");
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxFehler, "****");
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxParameter, "");
```

At this point we got rid of 17 Lines and introduced only 4

Proceeding... The next step would be the enabling of the controls. It seems that you treat again all Textboxes inside the same groupbox also the same. So we can introduce another parameter for the enabling part into the method:

```
private void FillAllTextBoxes(GroupBox groupBox, string text, bool enable)
{
    List<TextBox> allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1 = groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();

    foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxesFromGroupBox1)
    {
        tb.Text = "";
        tb.Enabled = enable;
    }
}
```

and this allows us to remove the rest of the lines entirely without introducing new lines of code:

```
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxStart, "", true);
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxZiel, "", true);
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxFehler, "****", false);
FillAllTextBoxes(groupBoxParameter, "", true);
```

So now you are down at 4 lines (I see only 4 groupboxes in your screenshot) of code

Comment: @SonnyBlack I wrote the rest. Have a look

Comment: But what if i should make one text-box in the "groupBoxStart" enable and the other to false? If i make a foreach i should make all the groupBox enable or disable ...

Comment: @SonnyBlack "what if i should make one text-box in the "groupBoxStart" enable and the other to false?" then you need a rule based mapping, this can be achieved using a dictionary or a swith case. The more granular you go with your rules, the more code you will have to write. You can edit your post and give a further example, and we can try to solve this one also